# OAuth2: How to pass session data to the front end?

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, backend

In my OAuth flow, I am using the auth code grant type.

1. The front end (React.js) app directs to the OAuth server's login and scope grant pages
2. A redirect happens to an Express.js client app
3. The client app receives the auth code and does token exchange.

I am stuck at this point. i have saved the user and token data to a database. But I have no way of redirecting back to the front end (React.js) app while safely passing a user session:

1. Cookies can't be passed cross domain
2. Query strings are available but are captured in server logs and browser history.
3. Redirects are GET requests so I don't have access to a POST request body.

How do you safely pass session data to a front end after your OAuth process? I suspect my Auth flow is wrong at one or more points.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could simplify by using a client side flow in your ReactJS app:

- Login uses Authorization Code Flow (PKCE)
- SPA uses the OIDC client library
- The SPA receives an access token and can make cross domain API calls with it

It is difficult to see what value your ExpressJS client app brings - feels like it is adding unnecessary complexity.

**RESOURCES OF MINE**

Here are some notes that might be useful. The SPA code is quite a bit simpler than older solutions that had to switch between front and back ends' to handle security processing:

- [SPA and API code sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1)
- [Blog post on OAuth / HTTP messages](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/)